# How to prevent recreation of a Fragment when an item in NavgiagtionDrawer is pressed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, navigation-drawer

I have a main aivity with `navigationDrawer`, and each item in the `navigationDrawer` , when clicked, it shows its respective fragment. what i realized when any item in the `navigationDrawer` pressed is thtat, the fragment is recreated, or in other words, when i choose an item in the `navigationdrawer`, the fragment goes through `onCreateView`, 'onactivtyCreated', `onResume` and `onPause`.

my question is, is there any way to prevent recreation of the fragment when an item in the `NavigationDrawer` pressed?

Comment: without seeing your code it's very hard to deduce what's actually going on there

Comment: How do you handle the onClick? Do you use FragmentTransaction.replace?

Comment: @JordiSipkens yes i use transaction.replace

Comment: I always use the .add and the .hide(currentFragment). This won't rebuild the fragment from scratch. It will just resume if the fragment was already created.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a local variable which will hold currently selected fragment index.
When a navigation drawer item is clicked, just check if selected item is your current fragment. In pseudo-code something like:

```
void itemClicked(int pos) {
    if (pos != currentFragmentIndex {
        . . . initialize fragment
        currentFragmentIndex = pos
    }
}
```